# move mouse relatively in Linux

Tags: python-3.x, autokey

I want to move my mouse relatively to the right. I already installed

- Python (3.8.2 (default, Jul 16 2020, [GCC 9.3.0])
- inside AutoKey 0.95.10.

My prototype (below) can do absolutely move. Is that possible with autopilot.input or do I have to try something different?

```
from autopilot.input import Mouse
mouse = Mouse.create()
mouse.move(3600, 80, animate=True, rate=1000, time_between_events=0.01)
```

## I read: https://phone.docs.ubuntu.com/en/apps/api-autopilot-development/autopilot.input.Mouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it moves the mouse relatively using `autopilot.input`.

to install:

`sudo apt-get install python3-autopilot`

```
from autopilot.input import Mouse
mouse = Mouse.create()
x, y = mouse.position()
mouse.move(x + 100, y + 100)
```

Comment: works long time. gives me now this error: 
``` Script name: 'autopilot-test'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/autokey/service.py", line 485, in execute
    exec(script.code, scope)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autopilot.input' ```