# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autopilot.input'

Tags: python, python-3.x

i use this little script from https://stackoverflow.com/a/63396200/2891692

in the new installed Ubuntu i installed **python3-autopilot** again (`sudo apt-get install python3-autopilot`).
seems i have the newest version:

```
python3-autopilot is already the newest version (1.6.0+17.04.20170313-0ubuntu8).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

but my python script here

```
from autopilot.input import Mouse
```

gives to following error:

```
Script name: 'autopilot-test'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/autokey/service.py", line 485, in execute
    exec(script.code, scope)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autopilot.input'
```

i tried proposals for this problem from  https://askubuntu.com/a/316103/1017209
but they dont't work for me, as you could see below:

1.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:autopilot/ppa
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install libautopilot-qt python-autopilot
Package libautopilot-qt is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'libautopilot-qt' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package python-autopilot
```

2. 

```
dpkg -l python-autopilot
dpkg-query: no packages found matching python-autopilot
```

## first test it i new Kubuntu then try reinstall al python stuff

as test i installed Kubuntu on other HDD (today (2021-02-28) and my `mouse-autopilot-test.py` works like expected.

then (2021-02-28) i tried repair my working OS like so (without success) :

### [uninstall python3](https://gist.github.com/zhensongren/811dcf2471f663ed3148a272f1faa957) - both configuration and data files of python3.x and it's dependencies  (takes some minute):

`sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python3.*`

### try reinstall my most used pyton

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python3-pkg-resources python3-setuptools
sudo apt-get install autokey-qt
sudo apt-get install python3-autopilot
```

### error when running mouse-autopilot-test.py :

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autopilot.input'`

---

what could i do to fix that?

Comment: According to your comment on your own answer, I would say try to install an older version. Seems that some update changed the code and now this import doesn't work

Comment: i dont thnk so. but i try, but i dont know how to do that. I have the idea that it might collide with another packet. I think that's mouse. I'm trying to uninstall it but can't find how.
you maybe know how to do that? i did not found it yet by 
`pip3 uninstall Mouse`

Comment: I got the problem again  in reinstalling Kubuntu after a few weeks. I tried to reconstruct it in virtualbox kubuntu clients. So far, however, everything goes without a problem there.